# R: running out of memory using `strsplit`

Tags: r, memory-management

I am running out of memory using `strsplit` (presumably); here is the code:

```
split.fields <- function (frame, fields, split, suffix, ...) {
  for (field in fields) {
    v <- sapply(strsplit(frame[[field]],"@",...),"[",1)
    frame[[paste0(field,suffix)]] <- frame[[field]]
    frame[[field]] <- v
  }
  frame
}
split.version <- function (frame, fields)
  split.fields(frame, fields, split="@", suffix="Ver", fixed=TRUE)
> gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 238165 12.8     467875   25   407500 21.8
Vcells 369492  2.9     905753    7   905631  7.0
> frame <- data.frame(browser = sample(c("Chrome@28","Chrome@27","Firefox@21","Firefox@22","IE@9","IE@8"), 1e7, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> str(frame)
'data.frame':   10000000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ browser: chr  "IE@8" "Chrome@27" "Chrome@27" "Chrome@27" ...
> object.size(frame)
80000992 bytes
> gc()
           used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   240555 12.9     467875  25.0   407500  21.8
Vcells 10373979 79.2   34109873 260.3 40534688 309.3
> system.time(frame <- split.version(frame,"browser"))
   user  system elapsed 
 73.700   0.872  74.831 
> object.size(frame)
160001248 bytes
> str(frame)
'data.frame':   10000000 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ browser   : chr  "IE" "Chrome" "Chrome" "Chrome" ...
 $ browserVer: chr  "IE@8" "Chrome@27" "Chrome@27" "Chrome@27" ...
> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   264888  14.2   16652260 889.4  31376740 1675.7
Vcells 20459856 156.1   95461025 728.4 119226749  909.7
```

This all looks more or less reasonable except that the `R` process's RSS is now **1.6G**.

This appears to imply that the 1675.7Mb of Ncells in the `max used`
column have not been returned to the OS.

I don't care much about the OS not getting back the RAM, what I do care
is that to process 80M of data R allocated 1.6G (and on my real data it
runs out of the physical RAM available)

Is there a way to make this more memory efficient?

E.g., maybe converting the character vector to a factor and operating on
its levels would help?

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `substr` and `regexpr`:

```
x <- c("Chrome@28","Chrome@27","Firefox@21","IE@8")
substr(x,1,regexpr("@",x)-1)
[1] "Chrome"  "Chrome"  "Firefox" "IE"
```

Comment: this seems to be faster than eddi's.

Answer (score 3):

What @James said, or even simpler:

```
x <- c("Chrome@28","Chrome@27","Firefox@21","IE@8")
sub('@.*', '', x)
#[1] "Chrome"  "Chrome"  "Firefox" "IE"
```