# Sort by absolute value

Tags: r, sorting

Does anyone know how to sort a vector in R by absolute value, so `(-2, 3, 1) -> (1, -2, 3)` etc?

If I were doing it in python I'd create a pair of every value and its sign, sort the list of pairs by the absolute value then reapply the sign, but I'm very new to R so have no idea how to do this.

Cheers

Comment: `x[order(abs(x))]` ?

Comment: Incidentally, in Python it would be easier to do `x.sort(key=abs)` rather than create the pairs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Arun's method is TRT:

```
v[order(abs(v))]
```

where `v` is the vector to be sorted.

Notes:

- This creates a new vector `abs(v)` of the same size as `v`.
  This is not very memory-efficient, but I don't think this can be avoided in `R`,
  like it is done in, e.g., Lisp: [`(sort #'< v :key #'abs)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm) or Python: [`v.sort(key=abs)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable).
- This temp vector allocation is not necessarily a bad thing: you do lose memory, but you win time because the accessor key is called only `N` times, not `N*log(N)` times, which is especially important when the key is not cheap (unlike `abs` or a structure field).
- To be more precise, the vector `abs(v)` is garbage collected very soon, but its allocation (and, especially, [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132548/850781)) are expensive for large vectors and may be actually problematic if the memory is tight.

See also:

- [`sort`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html)
- [`order`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html)
- [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1296646/850781)

Comment: But that vector is ephemeral, isn't it?

Comment: @Carl For sorting? Is that even possible?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I may have used the wrong term-- isn't it true that the vector `abs(v)` is not in the parent environment & will disappear on the next garbage collection?  So it may affect peak RAM but won't be permanent.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: of course it can be GCed right away, but neither allocation nor collection are cheap for huge vectors and may fragment memory for small ones.

Comment: Got it.  On to a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort method (no, not really :-) )

Comment: @Carl Ah, I thought you were referring to a [lazily evaluated vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Working_with_infinite_data_structures), i.e. it not being in memory at all. As sds said, whether it’s garbage collected immediate or sticks around in the parent frame doesn’t matter from a performance point of view (GC’ing is quite expensive, and if no memory is available in RAM it may have to be swapped to disk, which is also slow).

Comment: We are talking about a *vector* here. If the OP has issues to store a vector (even of size 1e7+) and create a copy of that vector, then probably he should be thinking about data structures to store the vector efficiently in the first place (RLE or what not). With the hardware prices now-a-days, this is almost never an issue IMHO.

Comment: @Arun: I have been hearing this "HW is cheap" mantra for 15+ years; I have been struggling with RAM scarcity on my box all this time. Yes, HW is _relatively_ cheap, but that is no excuse for wasteful RAM usage, just like it is not excuse for, e.g., using quadratic instead of linearithmic algorithms.

Comment: @sds, I guess my limits for compromise between speed and memory usage and more importantly spending a bit on hardware (especially when working on big-data and using R) are much different from yours (I dint advocate using quadratic time to linear time algorithms at all).

Comment: @Arun: I don't think we have anything to argue about.

Answer (score 2):

I found it useful to package this in a function so that I could pass a vector to it, and also so that there was the option of using other options in the `order` function like `decreasing`. It is essentially based on [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19435240/180892).

```
sort_abs <- function(x, na.last = TRUE, decreasing = FALSE) {
    x[order(abs(x), na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)] 
}
```

For example,

```
> sort_abs(c(-1,NA,2,-2))
[1] -1  2 -2 NA
> sort_abs(c(-1,NA,2,-2), decreasing = TRUE, na.last = FALSE)
[1] NA  2 -2 -1
```