# Interpretation of gc() result in R

Tags: r, garbage-collection

How to interpret result of `gc()` :

```
Garbage collection 9 = 1+0+8 (level 2) ... 
10.7 Mbytes of cons cells used (49%)
40.6 Mbytes of vectors used (72%)
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  198838 10.7     407500 21.8   350000 18.7
Vcells 5311050 40.6    7421749 56.7  5311504 40.6
```

and how can we see if any garbage have been collected ?

Comment: this is usefull to know because it helps to learn when you should and shouldn't call gc() in your script

Comment: I think this question is answered at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14580233/602276

Answer (score 4):

Under the initial line it tells you the totals in con cells(Ncells -that is a 28 byte for 32 bit system and 56 bytes for a 64 bit system... )  then the total in vector cells (Vcells , they are 8 bytes)

The following table just breaks down how it was distributed:

The number cleared now under used, the number which would have triggered automatically and the max used PRIOR to `gc()` in the third column is the amount used since the prior reset.

If you want to see more details `?gc()` in the console.....you get it all! And the base manual for R explains how garbage collection works. And `?Memory` gives you an idea of how memory is allocated.

*Edit:*
Finally, to see the results of a garbage collection, you could use an external resource monitoring applications. In windows, that just amounts to keeping the Task Manager open. In unix/linux, you could consult `htop`, or in macOS, the Activity Monitor app.